# InvocationTargetException when using AccessControler.doPrivileged in a signed applet

Tags: java, javascript, security, applet, invocationtargetexception

I'm having the following method in an applet which is called via JavaScript

```
public String getAString()
    {
        Object rc = AccessController.doPrivileged(
        new java.security.PrivilegedAction() 
        {
            public Object run()
            {
                try
                {
                    return "OK";
                }
                catch (Throwable t)
                {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                    return "ERROR: " + t.getMessage() + " " + t.getCause();
                }
            }
        });


        // Return value
        return rc.toString();
    }
```

The applet is signed using a certificate created with keytool

When I call `getAString()` if throws the `InvocationTargetException`.
If I call other methods which don't use the AccessController class, I'm not having this problem.

Also, each time I open the browser I'm asked to allow the applet to run even the the applet is signed.

How can I fix this?

**edit**

I added a button and now I'm getting more info:

> signer information does not match signer information of other classes
>   in the same package

I'm using a third party archive. In the original form is unsigned, but I signed it using the same cert (although with different commands).

**edit 2**
Here is how I sign the jars

```
keytool -genkey -keystore vkeystore -keyalg rsa -dname "CN=XXX, OU=XXX, O=XXX, L=Atlanta, ST=GA,C=NL" -alias printer -validity 3600 -keypass XXX-storepass XXX

jarsigner -keystore vkeystore -storepass XXX -keypass XXX -signedjar JSPrintS.jar JSPrint.jar printer

jarsigner -keystore vkeystore -storepass XXX -keypass XXX -signedjar jPDFPrintS.jar jPDFPrint.jar printer
```

JSPrint.jar contains the applet

edit 3

the applet definition is (located in JSPrint.jar)

```
package Eplatforms;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.AccessController;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

import com.XXX.pdfPrint.PDFPrint;

public class JSPrint extends JApplet implements ActionListener
....
```

jPDFPrint.jar is a third party jar

**EDIT 4**

I tried to minimize the problem a bit and I found out that when calling AccessControler.doPrivileged from a jar file (even signed one), I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestPrivileges$1
        at TestPrivileges.getAString(TestPrivileges.java:14)
        at TestPrivileges.main(TestPrivileges.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestPrivileges$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here is a testing class:

http://pastebin.com/EgmdwuqL

Notice that calling other methods doesn't raise this exception.

Here is how I compile and run it:

```
javac TestPrivileges.java
java TestPrivileges
jar cvf TestPrivileges.jar TestPrivileges.class
jarsigner -keystore vkeystore -storepass My0Company -keypass My0Company -signedjar TestPrivilegesS.jar TestPrivileges.jar printer
copy TestPrivilegesS.jar x /Y
copy TestPrivileges.jar x /Y
cd x
java -classpath TestPrivilegesS.jar TestPrivileges
java -classpath TestPrivileges.jar TestPrivileges
cd ..
```

A quick for vkeystore:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore vkeystore -keyalg rsa -dname "CN=MyCompany, OU=MyCompany, O=MyCompany, L=Atlanta, ST=GA,C=NL" -alias printer -validity 3600 -keypass My0Company -storepass My0Company
```

The first run works ok (probably because the class file is in the same directory).
Then I create to archives, one signed and another unsigned. When I run them, I got those errors. Notice the jars are in a separate folder which contains only those jars and no class file.

Comment: Which line is tossing the `InvocationTargetException`? I'm having a hard time finding anything in the block that can even cause that exception.

Comment: @Krroae27 there is no specific line. I'm calling the method with JavaScript alert(appletName.getAString());

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826669/trouble-calling-an-applet-method-from-page

Comment: Why is this code block using `AccessController.doPrivileged`?  I would expect it to work without it, unless `"OK"` actually means something like `System.getProperty("user.home")`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, see my update. The actual error is because two jars are considered to be signed with different certificates, even I'm using the same certificate..

Comment: @AdrianIftode its not that there is different signers but that there is different signers for the classes in the **same package**. A common overlooked area is for multiple jars to have classes in the default package.

Comment: @Krroae27, let's post anything here, just not to spam Andrew's mailbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I am with Andrew on this.</strike>

I've created an app that should help us find the code signing issue.

https://gist.github.com/2596125

(Since we don't want to Spam Andrew I've created this.)

With more information that finally came out it seems that you are not packing the `TestPrivileges$1` class with the jar.

To fix this do this for jar packing:

```
jar cvf TestPrivileges.jar TestPrivileges.class TestPrivileges$1.class
```

Comment: Right, I didn't run it on a signed jar. Here is the new output Checked Files: 1208
Found Unique Packages: 77
Unique CS: 1

Comment: @AdrianIftode and no issues are out printed? If not this is defiantly a weird one.

Comment: Thanks for your code. I'll try other ways.. but I just got tired, 10 hours with this already. I'll try to find some tutorials and read them with patience. Since I'm not a Java dev, maybe this is the best approach (to read first a bit:)). I'll comeback with the results next week probably.

Comment: That makes little to no sense... Did you include all of the jars being loaded in to the applet? As what the out print is telling me is that you only have 1 unique CS on all of the jars and nothings is conflicting in the packages. I've gona ahead and was able to get the expected results locally.... I'm off to lunch but I would love to hear if you ever figure it out.

Comment: @AdrianIftode 1 last try.. https://gist.github.com/2596125 I get your response when I come back.

Comment: I tested it again. I got 2 CSs when using archives signed with different vkeystores and 1 when signed with same vekeystore, so your code works OK. I don't think the problem is here, please check my 4th update.

Comment: @AdrianIftode "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestPrivileges$1" Indicates the you didn't include that class when building the jar, do this"jar cvf TestPrivileges.jar TestPrivileges.class TestPrivileges$1.class"

Comment: I was just looking for this "strange" file.. I'll come back

Comment: Yep, you're right. Can you edit the answer so I can accept this? And many many thanks!!

Comment: @AdrianIftode I've modified my answer to reflect the new information. Glad it is working for you!

Answer (score 1):

### New theory

The 3rd party Jar was already signed when it was signed it with your certificate.  Now there are 2 lots of information on digital keys inside the Jar, which is confusing the JRE.

Either use the original Jar, as it was, or remove the digital signatures and sign it again with your own certificate.

### Earlier answer

> signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the **same package**
>
> The actual error is because **two jars** are considered to be signed with different certificates, even I'm using the same certificate.

I suspect that the problem comes down to the part of the error/comment that I made **bold**.
Classes in the **same package** must be in the **same Jar.**

Comment: I have on class, one package and the resulted jar (the applet itself). I import also another jar, which is signed with the same keystore

Comment: I updated the question, maybe something wrong with the signing

Comment: What ***packages*** are in each Jar?

Comment: I hope we are referring to the same thing. The first jar JSPrint.jar (with the applet class) is in a package named Eplatforms and the second jar (which is a third party one) has the package name com.XXXX.pdfPrint.PDFPrint. (When I say package I'm thinking to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package and sorry for my ignorance, I'm not a java developer)

Comment: yes, import com.qoppa.pdfPrint.PDFPrint is a class located in jPDFPrint.jar Should I rename package Eplatforms to package JSPrint?

Comment: Don't rename any packages.  `JSPrint` is fine in `Eplatforms` for now.  It seems my first answer made an incorrect presumption.  See my **New theory**.

Comment: This is a concept and I am not sure if it will function as I plan. https://gist.github.com/2596125

Add all the jars to the File[] and then run it.

Comment: @Krroae27, thanks, I run it and it printed nothing. I also run it on a unsigned jar file and it printed nothing :) I guess something wrong

Comment: @Krroae27 
Checked Files: 1208
Found Unique Packages: 77
Unique CS: 0

Comment: @AdrianIftode are you not running this on the signed jars?